# Provider cannot be found above widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ListPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPosts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListPosts> createState() => _ListPostsState();
}

class _ListPostsState extends State<ListPosts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final posts = Provider.of<List<PostModel>>(context) ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(post.creator),
          subtitle: Text(post.text),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

It gives me this error on the provider and I checked everywhere but I cannot find any solution:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this ListPosts Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

I checked in other post and tutorials but could not find a good solutions, a lot of people are talking about to fix the widget tree but I believe mine is ok.

Comment: how are you creating List<PostModel>?

Comment: Share your provider class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be your answer.
Just Follow the below code.

Your Model Class:

```
class PostModel {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  PostModel({this.id, this.userId, this.title, this.body});

  factory PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PostModel(
      id: json['id'],
      userId: json['userId'],
      title: json['title'] ?? "",
      body: json['body'] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Your Provider Class:

```
class PostDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<PostModel> post = [];

  getPostData(context) async {
   
    post = await getPostData(context); //This method will bring your posts data in formate of List<PostModel>

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Your UI Screen:

```
class ListPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListPosts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListPosts> createState() => _ListPostsState();
}

class _ListPostsState extends State<ListPosts> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final postProvider = Provider.of<PostDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    postProvider.getPostData(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<PostModel> posts = Provider.of<PostDataProvider>(context).post;

    return posts.isEmpty ? const Center(child: 
      CircularProgressIndicator()):ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(post.creator),
          subtitle: Text(post.text),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Provider class? So I can make some sense.

Comment: im using the provider package. I did not create a class for any provider

Comment: Using this code I get an error on the getPostData in the UI part saying it does not exist while  i created. Edit: I fixed that, and I got back to the error of the question.

Comment: @vadi25 just go through [this medium article](https://maneesha-erandi.medium.com/handling-api-requests-with-flutter-provider-944e3258c5ca).
There is a proper implementation of the provider in a flutter.

Comment: That was perfect it solved it and helped me understando how it works, thank you for the help

Comment: I am grateful that it works for you. Please vote or mark the solution so, others can take advantage of it and help to reach out their solution.